# EncryptByKey MS SQL Is it appropriate to encrypt the password for login?

Tags: c#, sql-server, encryption, password-encryption

I have been looking for a way to encrypt credentials in my SQL Server database, and I found the T-SQL function [**ENCRYPTBYKEY**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/encryptbykey-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16):

> Encrypts data by using a symmetric key.
>
> ```
> EncryptByKey ( key_GUID , { 'cleartext' | @cleartext }  
>     [, { add_authenticator | @add_authenticator }  
>      , { authenticator | @authenticator } ] )
> ```
>
> EncryptByKey uses a symmetric key. This key must be open. If the symmetric key is already open in the current session, you do not have to open it again in the context of the query.

I'm not sure if it's appropriate to use it to encrypt passwords because I can only find commands in SQL, and all I can find is encrypted information like credit card numbers.

If I want to use it to encrypt a passworda, can it? Is that appropriate use-case?

I can't find an example to write the code.

Comment: The common approach is to hash the passwords not to encrypt and it is done in the application layer.

Comment: @Eldar Does that mean nobody uses EncryptByKey to encrypt their passwords ?

Comment: I can not speak for everyone but yes.

Comment: it might make sense to encrypt password if you need to use them to communicate to another system, ie. you encrypt when you need to be able to reverse the value. For normal passwords checking when you login, you usually don't need to get the original password, as long as you can compare *hashed* values of the password stored and the one passed

Comment: @siggemannen  using encryptbykey can compare passwords in web login ?

Comment: the other way around :) you should use hashing when comparing passwords on login.

Comment: But let's say you have some third-party API you wanna call in your application. Then you could use encryptkey to store the login to that api in your db

Comment: @siggemannen Bcrypt and EncryptByKey, which one is more secure or worth using?

Comment: That's something you can probably google and ask a new question about :)